# Rendering Modal using React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and thus the question,

I'm rendering a react-bootstrap `Modal` during form validation.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from "react";
import {Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";

const CustomModal = (props) =>{
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={true} animation={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>{props.message}</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={...}}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
};
export default CustomModal;
```

How do I implement the onClick on the `Button`to close this Modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code as given below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from "react";
import {Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";

const CustomModal = (props) =>{
    const [isModalOpen, setModal] = useState(true); // You can pass default state (true/false) from props as parameter into useState. i.e. useState(props.isModalOpen)
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={isModalOpen} animation={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>{props.message}</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setModal(false)} >
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
};
export default CustomModal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `onHide={ () => setModal(false)}` to `<Modal... >` for using `closeButton`
and for `Button` add `setModal(false)` to onClick.

```
const CustomModal = (props) =>{
    const [isModalOpen, setModal] = useState(true); // You can pass default state (true/false) from props as parameter into useState. i.e. useState(props.isModalOpen)

    return (
      <div >
            <Modal  show={isModalOpen} onHide={ () => setModal(false)} animation={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>{props.message}</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                     <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setModal(false)} >
                        Close1
                    </Button> 
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
};
```

for more code efficiency you can extract `() => setModal(false)` and put in function.
like `handleClose() { setModal(false);  }`

```
const CustomModal = (props) =>{
    const [isModalOpen, setModal] = useState(true); // You can pass default state (true/false) from props as parameter into useState. i.e. useState(props.isModalOpen)
    const handleClose=({isOpen})=> { setModal(isOpen);//Do somthings els for example remove temporary variables
      }
    return (
      <div >
            <Modal  show={isModalOpen} onHide={ () => handleClose(false)} animation={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>{props.message}</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                     <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => handleClose(false)} >
                        Close1
                    </Button> 
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have a hard-coded value for show={true}. Instead, use a variable with the value of True. Then using a function with onClick, you can set the variable to false in order to close the modal.

e.g. `show={isOpen}`